# More concise way of saying this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, artificial-intelligence

I have written this:

[image]

For the one highlighted in red, is there a more compact way of writing it?

Comment: Each $D_i$ is the same here, since there is no use of $i$ in the set-builder notation for $D_i$.  Why do you need the subscripts?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I don't think you need that. You can directly define $D$ as

$$ D = \left\{D_i\right\}_{i = 1}^6$$ and you say $D_i = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} | 0 \leq x \leq 9\}$, then there is no need for $\forall i \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, 6\right\}$.

Comment: Oh ok, so in the definition of $D$, isn’t that for a sequence, though?

Comment: I remember $\left\{ \right\}$ is used for defining a set and $( )$ is used for a sequence

Comment: Cool, got it, thank you! Just wanted to clarify